# Поиск и замена символов переноса и табуляции

Tags: python

Имеется строка:

```
<i class=\"font-icon icon-bottom-open no-functionality\"></i>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h4>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"stock\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

Как можно избавиться от \r, \t, \n? \ в названии класса?.replace не работает

```
re.sub('\t', "",string)
```

Тоже не работает

Comment: создайте минимальный пример кода. Проблема у вас не в xpath. Чтобы убедиться, можно `doc.cssselect('li.store-locator-list-item')` вызвать и убедиться, что оно у вас также не работает.

Comment: [пример](https://repl.it/@zed1/lxml-xpath-cssselect-example)

Comment: @jfs обновил  вопрос

Comment: @jfs либо как можно обработать такую страницу view-source:https://www.mvideo.ru/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/product-detail/tabs/availableStoresTable.jsp?productId=30031715&tab=list&cityId=CityCZ_975&ajax=true&json=true&page=1&viewAll=true

Comment: старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться. Если одну проблему решили, и обнаружилась новая задача, то задайте отдельный вопрос. По новому вопросу: откуда у вас `\"` взялось в строке? Что `print(ascii(your_string))` показывает?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "<i class=\"font-icon icon-bottom-open no-functionality\"></i>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h4>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"stock\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<i class=\"font-icon icon-bottom-open no-functionality\"></i>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h4>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"stock\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
string = string.strip()
```